# Lubavitch Hiskashrus

Tags: chabad, chasidut-hasidism, chassidic-rebbe

I was recently on a Lubavitch dating site in which the following profile question was asked:

Hiskashrus (select all that apply):
__ 770
__ Igros
__ Ohel

Is this question asking how you prefer to get advice from the Rebbe? I guess "770" would be going to the original shul (the one that is now Meshichist [?]); "Igros" would be seeking answers by opening to ~random pages in the Igros Kodesh; and "Ohel" would be visiting the ohel and maybe leaving kvitlach.

Is this correct?

Is there anything else involved in "770," for example?

What are the implications (re: Chabad subgroup, etc.) of each option?

Comment: I suggest to avoid this style of discussion here. It may lead to unsafe and unproductive arguments and damage the good learning atmosphere of this website

Comment: @kouty Thanks for your comment; I agree it's not an ideal question. I'll look out for further input from site members.

Comment: Simple answer: Meshichists tend to do 770 +/or Igros. Non-meshichists go to the ohel. I'm sure there are variations and exceptions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is asking in what way to you most feel connected to the Rebbe. Is it by going to 770, by reading the igrois koidesh, or by going to the oihel. All three of these are associated with the Rebbe but a particular person might find one of them more favorable.

There are those who don't go to the Oihel and instead only go to 770 and when asking the Rebbe for advice they put their letter into igrois and look at the answer. I don't know how many people follow this I just know it exists. From my point of view this is difficult to understand as these actions were never instructed by the Rebbe.

The other is going to the Oihel. Something the Rebbe himself stressed many times in reference in the previous Rebbe and everything that applies to the previous Rebbe also applies to the Rebbe. Going to the oihel can be to write a letter or simply to be near the daled amois of the Rebbe and sit in learn in the tents adjacent to the oihel.

Unrelated but perhaps if these are questions that aren't so related to you it might be a good question to ask if you are on the right dating website for you?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Don't worry; I am not on that dating site :)

Comment: Maybe those people don't go to the ohel because they don't believe he Shlit"a is in there...?

Comment: @SAH - That is true. There were some at the time of the Rebbe's death who did not believe he actually died, and there are still some who think this way and refuse to visit the Ohel.

Comment: @SAH and Ezra that may be so but that doesn't follow in my opinion. understanding what it means that a tzadik hasn't passed away isn't so simple. Let me give you an example of what I mean Rebbi Yehuda hanassi before his passing asked for his room to stay set up in the same way and after his passing he came back to make kiddush for his family. The only reason he stopped is someone outside his family saw him and he didn't want to give the impression that b/c others didn't do this they weren't tzadikim. Yet at the same time there is no reason to think there wasn't a burial or a shiva.