# What is the significance of 770 for Chaba"d?

Tags: number, chabad

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/770_Eastern_Parkway#Symbolism_of_.22770.22) explains the significance of the number 770 for Chaba"d. What isn't clear is if the rebbe made this comment after the purchase of the home or if Agudat Anshei Chaba"d specifically sought (or tried to, and Hashem helped it happen) this address or some other address with 7's in them.

I know this concept may sound odd esp. when seeking a home in NYC. However, I gather that in 1940, Crown Heights probably had more available housing choices than they do, now, so there's a possibility that, say 777 Eastern Parkway may have been available.

Comment: R' Yosef Yitzchak Schneersohn did not mention the significance of the number 770 (to my knowledge); it was the next Rebbe, R' Menachem Mendel Schneersohn, who did.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/69601/lubavitch-hiskashrus

Comment: Clearly the Rebbe Mamash said it, not the Rebbe Rayatz.  
See [here](http://he.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/3140299).

Comment: DanF, I'm not sure I entirely understand your question here. The Wikipedia article you link clearly gives you all the information you need. Please [edit](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/86364/edit) to clarify.

Comment: http://www.insidechassidus.org/sichos/296-sefer-hasichos-muga/1446-beis-rabbeinu-shebibavel-5752.html

Comment: It isn't clear what you are asking about. Are you asking about the decision making process that was used in purchasing 770 Eastern Parkway by the previous Lubavitcher Rebbe, meaning Rabbi Yosef Yitzchok Schneerson? Prior to its purchase by Chabad, it served as a medical clinic where abortions were performed. See the following link: http://lubavitch.com/news/article/2057949/August-16-1940-770-Purchased.html

Comment: @YaacovDeane I guess it's the "chicken / egg" type question. What came first? Buying 770 because the number had some significance or creating the significance after they bought it?

Comment: @ezra You refer to Rav Menachem Mendel as "Rebbe Mamash"? :-) :-) :-)

Comment: @DanF - Yes, I get tired of writing `the Rebbe, R' Menachem Mendel Schneersohn` all the time so I've abbreviated it to `the Rebbe Mamash`. By the way, as far as the "chicken or the egg" thing you mentioned, I think you'll get a different answer depending on who you ask, with some saying it happened by total coincidence, by accident with Hashem's guidance (Chabad), or that the Rebbe Rayatz and Mamash _mamish_ (no pun intended) knew the significance (Meshichist).

Comment: @ezra The Rebbe was actually referred to as the "Ramash" (`[R]' [M]enachem (Mendel) [S]chneersohn`) prior to his becoming Rebbe.

Comment: @Ploni - Thanks! I'll start using `Rebbe Ramash` instead.

Comment: @Ploni was reffered to as such and stopped being reffered to as such when the Rebbe accepted the leadership of being rebbe. I have only heard elter chassidim using this

Comment: http://www.insidechassidus.org/sichos/296-sefer-hasichos-muga/1446-beis-rabbeinu-shebibavel-5752.html

Comment: I just found today a [teshuva from Rav Moshe to the Lubavitcher Rebbe](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=920&st=&pgnum=14), where he refers to him as `[MO]reinu [H]a[R]av [M]enachem [M]endel`, which would come out to be, for your purposes, `Ramam`. (CC @Laser123)

Comment: seems post hoc. in any case i would be interested to hear a chabad argument that it isn't post hoc.

Comment: Just study the bais rabenu shebebavel sicha of the rebbe and you'll see what's the 770